# OpenCL MultiGPU slower than single GPU

Tags: opencl, multi-gpu

I am developing an application which performs some processing on video frame data. To accelerate it I use 2 graphic cards and process the data with OpenCL. My idea is to send one frame to the first card and another one to the second card. The devices use the same context, but different command queues, kernels and memory objects.

However, it seems to me that the computations are not executed in parallel, because the time required by the 2 cards is almost the same as the time required by only one graphic card.

Does anyone have a good example of using multiple devices on independant data pieces simultaneously?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Here is the resulting code after switching to 2 separate contexts. However, the execution time with 2 graphic cards still remains the same as with 1 graphic card.

```
    cl::NDRange globalws(imageSize);
    cl::NDRange localws;

    for (int i = 0; i < numDevices; i++){
            // Copy the input data to the device
            commandQueues[i].enqueueWriteBuffer(inputDataBuffer[i], CL_TRUE, 0, imageSize*sizeof(float), wt[i].data);

            // Set kernel arguments
            kernel[i].setArg(0, inputDataBuffer[i]);

            kernel[i].setArg(1, modulusBuffer[i]);
            kernel[i].setArg(2, imagewidth);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < numDevices; i++){
            // Run kernel
            commandQueues[i].enqueueNDRangeKernel(kernel[i], cl::NullRange, globalws, localws);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < numDevices; i++){
            // Read the modulus back to the host
            float* modulus = new float[imageSize/4];
            commandQueues[i].enqueueReadBuffer(modulusBuffer[i], CL_TRUE, 0, imageSize/4*sizeof(float), modulus);

            // Do something with the modulus;
        }
```

Comment: Sorry, only the pointer to https://developer.nvidia.com/opencl#oclSimpleMultiGPU , and the hint that there was a time (around CUDA 3.0, quite a while ago) where NVIDIA cards could not run concurrently on Win Vista/7, ... but I hope that they fixed this until now.

Comment: @Marco13 the current Nvidia and AMD graphics drivers allow multiple GPUs to be used concurrently within the same application on Windows 7 and 8 (probably Vista too but I haven't tested on that).

Comment: @krisg Without seeing code I can only make generic suggestions: don't use any blocking API calls, only use clWaitForEvents/clFinish after dispatching work to all devices.  One side-effect of using a single context for both devices is that the buffers and images you allocate will be on both devices, i.e. both will have memory objects for frame 1 and 2, even though each device only needs one frame.  Personally, I just use a separate context for each device.

Comment: Thank you both for your answers. It really makes sense to switch to different contexts. I will try it out and post some code and report on the results later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your main problem is that you are using blocking calls. It doesn't matter how many devices you have, if you operate them in that way. Since you are doing an operation and waiting for it to finish, so no parallelization at all (or very little). You are doing this at the moment:

```
Wr:-Copy1--Copy2--------------------
G1:---------------RUN1--------------
G2:---------------RUN2--------------
Re:-------------------Read1--Read2--
```

You should change your code to do it like this at least:

```
Wr:-Copy1-Copy2-----------
G1:------RUN1-------------
G2:------------RUN2-------
Re:----------Read1-Read2--
```

With this code:

```
cl::NDRange globalws(imageSize);
cl::NDRange localws;

for (int i = 0; i < numDevices; i++){
        // Set kernel arguments //YOU SHOULD DO THIS AT INIT STAGE, IT IS SLOW TO DO IT IN A LOOP
        kernel[i].setArg(0, inputDataBuffer[i]);

        kernel[i].setArg(1, modulusBuffer[i]);
        kernel[i].setArg(2, imagewidth);

        // Copy the input data to the device
        commandQueues[i].enqueueWriteBuffer(inputDataBuffer[i], CL_FALSE, 0, imageSize*sizeof(float), wt[i].data);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < numDevices; i++){
        // Run kernel
        commandQueues[i].enqueueNDRangeKernel(kernel[i], cl::NullRange, globalws, localws);
    }

    float* modulus[numDevices];
    for (int i = 0; i < numDevices; i++){
        // Read the modulus back to the host
        modulus[i] = new float[imageSize/4];
        commandQueues[i].enqueueReadBuffer(modulusBuffer[i], CL_FALSE, 0, imageSize/4*sizeof(float), modulus[i]);
    }

    clFinish();

        // Do something with the modulus;
```

Regarding the comments to have multiple contexts, depends if you are ever going to comunicate both GPUs or not. As long as the GPUs only use their memory, theere will be no copy overhead. But if you set/unset kernel args constantly, that will trigger copys to the other GPUs. So, be careful with that.

The safer approach for a non-comunication between GPUs are different contexts.

---

I suspect your main problem is the memory copy and not the kernel execution, highly likely 1 GPU will fulfil your needs if you hide the memory latency:

```
Wr:-Copy1-Copy2-Copy3----------
G1:------RUN1--RUN2--RUN3------
Re:----------Read1-Read2-Read3-
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Using your code and hints led to better results also in the case with 1 GPU. The kernel execution takes about 4 ms for each image, and the data transfer - approximately 2 milliseconds. A single GPU is sufficient. I just wanted to evaluate the performance and compare the results of 1 and 2 GPUs. Unfortunately, even after I applied the changes that you proposed there is still no significant difference in the execution times between 1 and 2 GPUs.

Comment: 2ms transer and 4ms execution is a quite big IO overhead. Maybe you should try with pinned memory. Try to get the bottleneck first in the GPU operation (instead of the IO), only then you can check the multi-GPU approach. Another option to check your approach, is to remove the IO copy (do not read or write data). This way you will see if the multiGPU is faster than single GPU. (should be)